# Scope Change creating NULL values

Tags: vb.net

Can someone explain to me why my `newRow("Hit Cadence") = "No"` becomes `NULL` after
`if lp.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK` is found to be true?

I think it has something to do with the scope changing but don't know how to get around it. Basically if a person is late (did not hit cadence) they give a reason in another form pop up.

```
        If mastProcess <= Cadence.Add(New TimeSpan(0, 3, 0)) AndAlso mastProcess >= Cadence Then
            newRow("Hit Cadence") = "Yes"
        Else
            newRow("Hit Cadence") = "No"
            Using lp As New reasonlateForm
                If lp.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                    newRow("Reason Why") = lp.reasonlatecmbBox.Text
                Else
                    Me.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Pick Creation Canceled..."
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End Using
        End If
```

Comment: What is `newrow`?  If you are worried about being new the thing to do is read [ask] and take the [tour] like you agreed to.

Comment: Firstly, your `newRow("Hit Cadence") = "No"` doesn't become NULL.  Do you actually mean that `newRow("Hit Cadence")` is `Nothing` or `DBNull.Value` after that?  If so then it's because it is set to that inside `lp`.  As we know nothing about `reasonlateForm`, we can't tell you how that happens.

Comment: I have removed the `sql` tag as there is nothing relating to SQL in your question.